# Setting variables from a dataset to the global environment so the variable can be used freely

Tags: r

So, I am using a dataset that is built into R called "mtcars". I am trying to do a correlation test between the variables "MPG" and "HP". This is my code so far...

```
data(mtcars,package = "datasets",envir = .GlobalEnv)
new_hp = log10(hp)
new_mpg = log10(mpg)
plot(new_hp,new_mpg,xlab = "Log10(Horsepower)",ylab = "Log10(MPG)")
abline(lm(new_mpg~new_hp))
cor.test(new_hp,new_mpg)
```

When I do this, the console tells me that the variables HP and MPG are not found (Object "variablename" not found). So, all the subsequent code fails due to no defined objects to operate on. Do I need to make the variables HP and MPG from the mtcars data set be in the global environment? If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For built-in data like `mtcars`, there is generally no need for explicitly calling `data()`. If you start a fresh R session and just type `mtcars` at the console you will see the data. This is due to the (not so new) lazy-loading features for data.

If you are working interactively at the console and get tired of typing `mtcars$` over and over again to refer to specific columns, a good tool is `with`.

For example, you might do:

```
with(mtcars,plot(log10(hp),log10(mpg),xlab = "Log10(Horsepower)",ylab = "Log10(MPG)"))
```

Alternatively, you can simply add the transformed versions first and then refer to them directly:

```
mtcars <- transform(mtcars,log_hp = log10(hp),log_mpg = log10(mpg))
with(mtcars,plot(log_hp,log_mpg,xlab = "Log10(Horsepower)",ylab = "Log10(MPG)"))
```

Comment: And of course plot and some other functions got a convenient data argument.

Answer (score 1):

You are not referencing the data set when you define new_hp and new_mpg

This will work:

```
new_hp = log10(mtcars$hp)
new_mpg = log10(mtcars$mpg)
```